# The wrong thread is the one sleeping

Tags: java, android, multithreading, events, sleep

I have an event in the main thread that creates another thread. This new thread must sleep for 60 seconds and then it must check the main thread state. My code is this:

```
public class Act extends Activity {
    Object lock=new Object();
    public class MainT implements LocationListener {
         public String str="";
         public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              synchronized(lock) {
                   str=String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())+" "+String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
                   new SecondT(str).start();
              }
         }

         class SecondT extends Thread {
              public String st;
              SecondT(String s) {
                   st=s;
              }

              public void run() {
                   waitSeconds();
              }

              public void waitSeconds() {
                   try {
                        Thread.sleep(60000);
                        synchronized(lock) {
                             if (str.equals(st))
                             Log.d("SecondT", "Same string.");
                        }
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                   }
              }
         }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        MainT mt = new MainT();
        locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 50, mt);
    }
}
```

The problem is that if a start that thread, it's the MainT that sleeps (the GPS event isn't called even if i pass new coordinates through the debug tool).

Comment: Can you post a complete runnable program that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I added the whole class.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain a bit more the behavior you are getting?  Is the main thread forking the other thread and then it sleeps?

Comment: Can you use log entries to track down where main is spending its time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that if a start that thread, it's the MainT that sleeps (the GPS event isn't called even if i pass new coordinates through the debug tool).

As @Joni mentions, it's hard to see where main would sleep unless the `synchronized` section of code that updates the string value is doing some complex operations that could take a long time.  Could it be that main is trying to fork 2 threads and the 2nd one is waiting for the lock?  If you provide more code we may be able to see your problem.

In terms of sharing the `st` value between the forked-thread and the main thread, you might consider something like an [`AtomicReference<String>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html).  This will allow you to `set(...)` the value in the forked thread and `get()` the value in main without locking.

Comment: The rest of the code is just the main activity that manages the android gps' code (with the `requestLocationUpdates()` method).

Comment: And you definitely _don't_ have the sleep in the lock and you are definitely calling `start()` on the thread and not `run()`? @AsAs